# Socrata SODA API: Select by day of week, hour, etc

Tags: socrata, soda

I'm looking for a SODA API function that would allow me to select/extract the day of week, hour, etc from a floating timestamp field. In other words, I'm looking for a SODA equivalent to SQL's `DATEPART`.

The API has a few function for manipulating timestamp fields, such as `date_trunc_y(...)`, but this is not quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Socrata has since added date extract functions that operate on timestamp columns.

See the "SoQL" Query functions listed here:
https://dev.socrata.com/docs/functions/

Socrata seems to use a Postgresql backend, so you might find the syntax comforting.